# Combining xargs parallel and mpirun

Tags: multithreading, xargs, slurm, mpiexec

I have an embarassingly parallel (bash) script that is running in a computing cluster.
The script is a shell script and is *not* linked to any MPI library: this means that the only way I can send the MPI rank to it, is with a command line parameter.

So Far, I only executed it within a single node, and the solution was simple:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #SBATCH --nodes=1
 N=16
 seq $N | xargs -P $N -I% my_script.bash % $N
```

How can I scale it with two nodes? If I just use '--nodes=2' and `N=32` then `xargs` will try to spawn all threads on the same node. On the other hand I cannot use `mpiexec` alone: because the script is not linked to `MPI` library and I do not know how tell the script which threads it is.

Comment: Does the solution HAVE to use MPI? It is extremely easy to do with GNU Parallel: seq $N|parallel -S server1,server2,: my_script.bash {} $N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `srun` within your submission script to do that:

```
seq $N | xargs -P $N -I% srun --exclusive -N1 my_script.bash % $N
```

This will use `srun` to launch your bash script and distribute it to the allocated CPUs.

Comment: I like the idea of this answer but wish it came with a simple test script to demonstrate that it is behaving as expected.